# Where to announce new Magento tools

Tags: discussion

I have produced a new tool for exploring Magento layout configurations but am unsure where the best place is for announcing details and soliciting feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some ideas:

- magehero.com
- Twitter
- The Magento Forums

Comment: thanks, I missed the new forum

Answer (score 2):

on http://www.reddit.com/r/Magento/